# Prime number between N and M

Tags: c++, function, loops, for-loop, primes

So I was trying to get the prime number between two numbers, it works fine but it also prints out odd numbers

```
int prime(int num1, int num2)
{
    int  sum{0};
    while (num1 <= num2)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
        {
            if (num1 % i == 0) //remainder needs to be zero
            {
                if (num1 % 2 == 0) continue; //continue the loop if the number is even
                if (i * num1 == num1 && num1 / i == num1)
                {//make sure it only prints prime numbers
                    cout << num1 << endl;
                    sum += num1;
                }
            }
        }
        num1++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSdKv.png)

I tried to make a for loop that iterates between 1 and N and if the remainder is zero it also checks if the number is even.. if it is then it continues the loop. and then i checked for prime numbers.. if (i * num1 == num1 && num1 / i == num1) i expected it to print out only prime numbers and last the sum of them but it also counts odd numbers

Comment: There is a little more to primes : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
You can also calculate them once store them (in memory or disk) and then reuse the calculated results.

Comment: Find out the smallest set for which you get wrong values, then [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to think about the code carefully. What values of `i` do you expect will be used for the test `if (i * num1 == num1 && num1 / i == num1)`? In particular, do you think that the value `1` will be used? (Why or why not? Did you check?) Will that condition be met, if `i` is equal to `1`? Can `i` be equal to `1`? (Hint: what part of the code determines the values used for `i`?) **Should** `i` ever be equal to `1`? (Hint: do you try dividing by 1 when solving the problem by hand?)

Comment: As written, a sub function `is_prime` would be useful (and testable independently).

Comment: `if (i * num1 == num1 && num1 / i == num1)` is equivalent to `if (i == 1 || num1 == 0)`...

Comment: `if (num1 % i == 0) //remainder needs to be zero` Not for prime numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This if statement

```
if (i * num1 == num1 && num1 / i == num1)
{//make sure it only prints prime numbers
    cout << num1 << endl;
    sum += num1;
}
```

is always evaluated for any number when `i` is equal to `1`.

So the code has a logical error.

At least there is no sense to start the for loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
```

with `i` equal to `1`.

Pay attention to that prime numbers are defined for natural numbers that is for numbers of unsigned integer types.

I would write the function at least the following way

```
unsigned long long int sum_of_primes( unsigned int first, unsigned int last )
{
    unsigned long long int sum = 0;

    if (not ( last < first ))
    {
        do
        {
            bool prime = first % 2 == 0 ? first == 2 : first != 1;

            for (unsigned int i = 3; prime && i <= first / i; i += 2)
            {
                prime = first % i != 0;
            }

            if (prime) sum += first;
        } while (first++ != last);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

For example if in `main` to write this statement

```
std::cout << "sum_of_primes(0, 10) = " << sum_of_primes( 0, 10 ) << '\n';
```

then its output will be

```
sum_of_primes(0, 10) = 17
```

Indeed in this range `[0, 10]` prime numbers are `2, 3, 5, 7` and their sum is equal to `17`.

Comment: Supposing that the `1` used in initializing the loop isn't a typo, it's a conceptual problem with the steps that need to be taken - in other words, a math or logic question, not a programming question. Either way, this does not make an on-topic question for Stack Overflow, and as such it should not be answered. (To the extent that the general question of "how do I find prime numbers using trial division" has value, questions like this one should instead be routed to a canonical, although they are probably still not good signposts.)

Comment: @Karl Knechtel. Is this a opinion or can I read a technical rule somewhere? If there is such a technical rule, can you please kindly guide me to there?

Comment: @AM With at least 3000 reputation, you can see the close reasons underneath the `Close` link on any question. The topicality requirements are described in [ask] and [answer] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. If you are unsure about anything (or have a disagreement), you can ask on https://meta.stackoverflow.com (of course, look for existing discussion there, first, too - there is an entire category of FAQ questions there).

Comment: I am very confident in my close vote and downvotes, but I will not discuss the matter here further. Please take it to Meta. (That said, labelling something "silly and wrong" is only condescension and rudeness, not an argument.)

Comment: Can you explain              bool prime = first % 2 == 0 ? first == 2 : first != 1;

            for (unsigned int i = 3; prime && i <= first / i; i += 2)
            {
                prime = first % i != 0;
            }

Aswell as the if(not) part